# ViewFlipper and the Gallery on the same activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I have `ViewFlipper` and the `Gallery` on the same activity. `ViewFlipper` periodically switch two view with simple fade animation. Problem is when I scrolling in Gallery at every switch start, Gallery stop animation and jump to nearest item. Is almost impossible to scroll if switch period is too short. I think that `ViewFlipper` start Animation which call `invalidate()` and this cause refresh Gallery, but why? `Gallery` is on the opposite side of screen, completely no reason  to refresh gallery on every animation start.

Comment: I found that it maybe doesn't cause animation but `child.setVisibility(View.GONE)` in `ViewAnimator` class. I tried to call `setVisibility(View.GONE)` on some my object during Gallery swype and it also cause stop animation of swiping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is caused by `child.setVisibility(View.GONE)` in `ViewAnimator` class it cause remeasure and redraw of whole activity screen :-(  I used source code put in on own package and modify it to `child.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`

I made bug report for this:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19581